# Permutation of n ,not all different things, taking r at a time

Tags: permutations

Please read it once again, it's not as easy as it seems.

Is there any Mathematical formula or finite approach to solve this type of problem.
Eg - Find the permutation of word "MALAYALAM" taking 5 at a time.

I have written a program which can solve this type of problem ,but I couldn't  found any method to do it on paper.

My programming approach -
(i) Find all the combination taking r at a time

(ii) Remove duplicates from combination by sorting

(iii) Find the permutation of individual combination and then sum up, to get the answer.

Please help me,
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of ways of forming 4 letter words using the letters of the word RAMANA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587851/number-of-ways-of-forming-4-letter-words-using-the-letters-of-the-word-ramana)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there *is* a formula.
The word has one **Y**, two each of **M** and **L** and four of **A**

and the formula would be to find the coefficient of $x^5$ in $5!(1+\frac{x}{1!})(1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!})^2 (1+\frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!})$

To understand why this works, you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587851/number-of-ways-of-forming-4-letter-words-using-the-letters-of-the-word-ramana)

Comment: Thanks frnd ,I got it

Comment: You're welcome !